# Missing Pepper SDK Android Studio Marketplace

Tags: android-studio, pepper

I'm working with a new notebook. I try to download and install the Pepper SDK for Android Studio, but it's missing in the marketplace. same problem for 3 diverent devices.
Someone got the sam eproblem or a solution?

[image]

I'm using Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 2
I also tryed older versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this plugin is available only for at most 2021.1.1 Patch 3, [according to versions page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8354-pepper-sdk/versions/stable)

install older version of Android Studio or don't use deprecated, not maintained and not actively developed software